# separate publisher for few publications

Tags: web8

we are trying set up separate publisher service for few publications. However it is working when primary publisher stopped state only. Secondary publisher service is not picking the request when primary publisher service is start.

[image]

Could you please let us know if required any specific configuration.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Maybe the primary publisher just picks up the jobs before the secondary gets to it? Have you tried with a queue of publishing tasks (more than the number of rendering threads of the primary publisher)?

Comment: we didn't tried with a queue of publishing tasks . However we are not depending on rendering thread of the primary publisher.

Comment: What I meant is that as long as the primary publisher has available rendering threads, it has capacity to pick up new tasks and it might get to it before the secondary publisher does.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the primary publisher is not filtering at all, so as long as the primary publisher is not busy (all rendering threads in use) there is nothing preventing the primary publisher from picking up publishing tasks for the subset of Publications configured on the secondary publisher.

Maybe this is fine; in this way the secondary publisher just provides additional capacity for a subset of Publications. Furthermore, there should be a bit of load balancing going on; the chance that a publishing task gets picked up by the secondary publisher should increase when the primary publisher gets busier.

If you want a strict segregation of Publications handled by the primary and secondary publisher, you would have to explicitly configure a subset of Publications for the primary publisher too.

To ease the pain of this explicit configuration a bit: note that the "Publisher (deploying)" queue is only used for scheduled deployment and there is hardly any work to be done by the publisher for those. So, you most probably don't have to segregate On Publication for those tasks (if any).